# Wordpress Mystyle theme Google Maps API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, google-maps, wordpress-theming

I'm using Mystyle theme for Wordpress and I have a problem displaying the google map using the Contact form that is included in the theme options. I can add longitute and latitude in the option but everytime I do it I get an "ooops something went wrong" error on the page. 
The map just doesn't load.

Is there a fix or should I use an alternative plugin for my wordpress contact page?

I am looking for the line in the Mystyle theme files and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed the API key for the google map. You must create a API key to make it working.

Please create a Google Maps Javascript API from below link.
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try going through the following series of WordPress tutorials and a GitHub post for a more complete explanation:

- [Integrating Google Maps in WordPress](https://tommcfarlin.com/google-maps-in-wordpress/)
- [Displaying Google Maps in WordPress](https://tommcfarlin.com/displaying-google-maps-in-wordpress/)
- GitHub post - [Using the Google Maps JavaScript API within the context of WordPress](https://gist.github.com/tommcfarlin/ccb88687def3e152b980#file-5-template-maps-with-map-part-2-php)

As discussed, you need the following:

- Get API credentials by navigating to the [JavaScript API page](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/)
- Include the actual API library
- Display a map within the context of WordPress template using `google.maps.event.addDomListener` as shown in the sample code within the [tutorial](https://tommcfarlin.com/displaying-google-maps-in-wordpress/).